# Wxpython script gives "TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not QString"

Tags: python, exception, wxpython

this simple wxpytohn script gives the following error, what is wrong? The error message doesnt give which line the error occurs in script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\plugins\externalconsole.py", line 721, in run_script_in_current_shell
    "and try again.") % osp.basename(filename), QMessageBox.Ok)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 198, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 173, in split
    while i and p[i-1] not in '/\\':
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not QString
```

This is the script:

```
import wx
import os


def getParentFolder():
    moduleFile = __file__
    moduleDir = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(moduleFile))[0]
    programFolder = os.path.abspath(moduleDir)
    parentFolder = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(programFolder, os.pardir))
    return programFolder, parentFolder

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150,150), size=(1200,900))
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.closeWindow)
        self.SetIcon(wx.Icon("plane.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO))
        self.Center()

        icons_folder = getParentFolder()[1] 

        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        scenario_menu = wx.Menu()
        database_menu= wx.Menu()
        settings_menu = wx.Menu()


        open_scenario = wx.MenuItem(scenario_menu, 101, '&Open\tCtrl+O', 'Open an existing scenario')
        open_scenario.SetIcon((wx.Icon(icons_folder+"\\open_dir.ico", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)))
        scenario_menu.AppendItem(open_scenario)

        scenario_menu.Append(102, "&Create", "Create new scenario")
        scenario_menu.Append(103, "&Save", "Save scenario")

        menubar.Append(scenario_menu, "&File")
        menubar.Append(database_menu, "&Database")
        menubar.Append(settings_menu, "&Settings")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MainWindow("CrewOpt")
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a spyderlib issue for this [here](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1540). Apparently it's closed, so maybe try updating your libraries and see if it's still a problem.

[Log](http://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/source/detail?r=2417e4646f961a66b26e2d7337ac83c0d42e51c9)

```
Log message

Executing script in current Python/IPython interpreter while no interpreter is
running was raising a TypeError exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]\spyderlib\plugins\externalconsole.py", line 722, in
run_script_in_current_shell
    "and try again.") % osp.basename(filename), QMessageBox.Ok)
  File "[...]\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\ntpath.py", line 198, in basename
    return split(p)[1]
  File "[...]\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\ntpath.py", line 173, in split
    while i and p[i-1] not in '/\\':
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not QString

Update  Issue 1540 
Status: Fixed

Affected files
    expand all   collapse all
    Modify  /spyderlib/plugins/externalconsole.py   diff
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that in

```
p[i-1] not in '/\\'
```

`p[i-1]` is a `QString` whereas Python expect a string. Maybe a

```
str(p[i-1]) not in '/\\'
```

solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce the error: my computer answers that ` MenuItem' object has no attribute 'SetIcon'`

Answer (score 0):

As of Dec.2015 it is strange that the same problem exists although the reported issue of #1540 was said to be fixed: The code containing (for example) this line:

```
newPath = os.path.dirname(newFile)
```

runs under spider. While compiling it in cmd in windows throws the TypeError:
    TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not QString

You may consider:

```
newPath = os.path.dirname(str(newFile))
```